# Doubled image while projecting video on surface

Tags: texturing, materials, video

I created plane, I did't modify it. Then created material, and texture, selected video as texture. And I got video forked into two parts by diagonal.
[image]

Comment: Please show your UV Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Perhaps you forgot to unwrap the mesh.

Tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tovu1A0LxeQ

In edit mode Unwrap your plane.  Select all vertices before you Unwrap.
Your UV Mapping appears incorrect.
Perform the UV Map again.  Have exactly 1 UV Map.

The time required for this is 88 seconds or less.

BSE and famous video websites have information on the topics of

Blender UV Map and Blender Unwrap.

By searching you can find a tutorial on those topics if necessary.

Comment: Post a new question please.  The video link is part of a series.  Search that series please for your topic tutorial.  And you can delete your comment immediately above.